# How can I can get a child class's properties into the parent class's methods

Tags: php, class, extends

I have two classes: The first class - Database - handles all the database actions, i.e., insert, update, delete. The other handles class specific actions for the user. The user class extends the database class. The User class has all of the properties in it and am trying to get the methods from the Database class to perform actions on the properties from the User class. So I'm instantiating User in test.php:

```
<?php 
require_once("user.php");
$user = new User();

$user->auth("Scott", "rascal");
echo $user->username;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

and I'm getting these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Database::$dbFields in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/projectx/application/models/db.php on line 24

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/projectx/application/models/db.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined property: Database::$tableName in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/projectx/application/models/db.php on line 83

Notice: Undefined property: Database::$id in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/projectx/application/models/db.php on line 85

Notice: Undefined property: Database::$dbFields in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/projectx/application/models/db.php on line 24

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/scottmcpherson/Sites/phpsites/projectx/application/models/db.php on line 24
```

Here's the user class:

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");

class User extends Database{

    public $dbFields = array('username', 'password');

    public $tableName = "users";
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    public function auth($user, $pass){
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
    
    }
}
?>
```

And here's the section of the database class that's giving me trouble:

```
<?php 
require_once("../config/main.php");

class Database{


 public $db;

public function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
}

public function connect(){
try {
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER."; dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function properties() {
    $properties = array();
    foreach ($this->dbFields as $field) {
        if (isset($this->field) || property_exists($this, $field)) {
            $properties[$field] = $this->$field;            
        }
    }
    return $properties;
}
```

I had everything working fine until I tried to extend the class and move the properties to the child class. How do I get past the errors and achieve this correctly?

Comment: You should rethink your design. Read up on what the extends relation actually is: I don't think it is appropriate in this case. You have a user class that might USE a database class, but it "is" not a database. For the problem an sich: As every User is a Database, and every user has the `dbFields`, every user can use the `dbFields` member and call `connect`. But NOT every Database is a user: Every Database can use the `connect()` function but it cannot use the `dbField` for it does not have one per se.

Comment: @Nanne That makes sense. First I tried using connect as a class on its own and bring in $db(The connection) into other classes as a global but I know enough to know that's not good practice. And I don't want to use the singleton so then I tried this approach, which apparently won't work. I'm stumped on this one. I need a way to call the connection into my classes or at least one class that can be extended.

Answer (score 3):

What you did seems like it should work, just make sure to construct a User object and not a Database object directly.  This is the exact point of class inheritance (having a parent run functions and reference properties that you don't have to code in every subclass).

That said, maybe try defining $dbFields as an empty array in your Database class (and your other subclass properties for that matter).  Not sure if it would fix it (I usually do the late-static-binding thing), but worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

In your parent class declare variables as static and if they exist in the child class, they will be used in the parent class. Check out Late Static Binding (LSB)

Answer (score 1):

You try to access `dbFields` in your Database class but it is declared in your User class.

IMO, you should declare the `dbFields` in your Database class & you can set this property in the User constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just had the same problem but I could figure this out using late static binding here is my example some of the codes are extra from my own just focus on the show_fields() function

```
<?php 
class x {
    protected static $table_name;
    public static $fields = array();
    public function __construct() {
    self::set_table_name();
    }
    public function called_class() {
    return __CLASS__;
    }
    public function set_table_name() {
    self::$table_name = static::called_class();
    }
    public function test() {
     echo self::$table_name;
    }
    public function show_fields() {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(static::$fields);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br />";
    foreach (static::$fields as $key => $value) {
        if(property_exists(static::$table_name, $value)) {
            echo static::$$value . "<br />";
        }
    }
    }
    }
    class y extends x {
        public static $fields = array('id','title');
    public static $id = 'new id';
    public static $title = 'new title';
    public function called_class() {
    return __CLASS__;
}
}
$xx = new x();
$yy = new y();
$yy->test();
$yy->show_fields();
```

?>